# Slick query by mapped colum

Tags: scala, slick

When you try to query by `MappedTo[Long]`:

```
for {
  game <- GamblrGame.table
  bet <- GamblrBet.table if game.id === bet.game
} yield (game, bet)
```

you get:

```
[error] /Volumes/Home/dev/gamblr/test/BotTest.scala:27: Cannot perform option-mapped operation
[error]       with type: (slicky.Slicky.ID, slicky.fields.FK[models.GamblrGame]) => R
[error]   for base type: (slicky.Slicky.ID, slicky.Slicky.ID) => Boolean
[error]         bet <- GamblrBet.table if game.id === bet.game
```

How should I use mapped columns in queries?

The `FK`:

```
case class FK[E <: IdEntity[E]](id: ID)(implicit tag: TypeTag[E])
  extends MappedTo[Long]
```

The `game` column in `GamblrBet.table`:

```
def game = column[FK[GamblrGame]]("GAME")
```